# Pass JQuery value to Javascript's variable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am new to jquery and javascript. I want to pass `id="val"` value to javascript's variable `scrt_var`. But my code returns `undefined` value.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
$('.value-plus').on('click', function () {
var divUpd = $(this).parent().find('.value'), newVal = parseInt(divUpd.text(), 10) + 1;
divUpd.text(newVal);
});

$('.value-minus').on('click', function () {
var divUpd = $(this).parent().find('.value'), newVal = parseInt(divUpd.text(), 10) - 1;
if (newVal >= 1)
divUpd.text(newVal);
});
</script>

<script>
var scrt_var = document.getElementById("val").value;
</script>

<div class="entry value-minus">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="val" class="entry value"><span>1</span></div>
<div class="entry value-plus active">&nbsp;</div>


<p><a class="item_add" href="addToCart.jsp?orderdetail=<%=orderId%>,<%=i.getItemID()%>,<%=c.getCategoryID()%>,<%=i.getPrice()%>," onclick="location.href = this.href + scrt_var;return false;">add to cart </a></p>
```

Output:
addToCart.jsp?orderdetail=107,10,15,23.0,undefined

Comment: You have three separate problems here (although the second will go away as a side effect of solving the third). See the duplicates.

Comment: Please read: [mcve]  the code in the question only needs 5 lines for the question as asked (and 2 of those are `<script></script>`)

Answer (score -1):

For your div:

```
scrt_var = $('#val').text();
```

For input box:

```
scrt_var = $('#val').val();
```

val is not a great value to choose as an id.

Comment: What's wrong with `var scrt_var = document.getElementById("val").value;`? They already have that in the question.

Comment: I understood the question to be about jquery not just javascript.

Comment: To rephrase: How does replacing some plain DOM with jQuery that does exactly the same thing *solve the problem*?

Comment: The don't do the same thing. the problem: document.getElementById("val").value; returns undefined (because divs don't have a value). The solution: $('#val').text(); (because they can have a text value, which is what Iunderstood was required)

Comment: I was referring to the second half of your answer (which was the *only* part when I made the comment since you edited it afterwards). Even the edit doesn't solve the problem because it is caused the intersection of three separate errors.

Comment: Only Input elements can return a "value". you are using <div> here, which can return a text, or html only